# KitKat target framework

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio, android-4.4-kitkat

I ran into this issue where in the SDK manager, API 19 (Android 4.4 KitKat) is checked and all packages are downloaded and up to date.

But when I go into the project properties, the latest proposed Target Framework is Jelly Bean 4.3

Is it possible to choose KitKat as a target framework as of now ?